# Probability of Choosing a Loaded Die

Tags: probability

I was hoping to get some help on this problem.  I am doing a Discrete Mathematics course right now and am finding it quite difficult.  Anyways here is the problem I am having problems with:

> Assume that you have two dice, one of which is fair, and the other is biased toward landing on six, so that 1/4 of the time it lands on six, and 1/6 of the time it lands on each of 2, 3, 4 and 5, and 1/12 of the time on 1. You choose a die at random, and spin it six times, getting the values 4, 3, 6, 6, 5, 5. What is the probability that the die you chose is the fair die?

Also the book we are using is crap and an example they gave in the book relating to dice I think is wrong:

[Is This Correct?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpG4i.png)

it is showing the $\frac17$, shouldn't it be $\frac16$ for a die sample space?

Comment: The book is defining a valid distribution...they say the die is "loaded", i.e. "not fair" and the six possible probabilities do add to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your added question: the book does it just fine: if 6 is twice as likely to come up as the others, then the probabilities do indeed become $\frac{2}{7}$ for the 6, and $\frac{1}{7}$ for the others.

For your original question:

You need to calculate the *conditional* probability that

$P(F|O)$

Where $F$ is the event of having picked the fair die, and $O$ the event of getting the values you got. That is *given* the outcomes that you got, what is the probability that you did pick the fair die?

And for that, you want to use Bayes' Theorem:

$$P(F|O) = \frac{P(O|F) * P(F)}{P(O)}$$

where:

$P(O) = P(O|F) * P(F) + P(O|F') * P(F')$

Now, $P(F)$ is the probability of picking the fair die *without* knowing the outcomes that you got. So this is the probability of picking the fair die when you picked one die initially and randomly. So, $P(F) = \frac{1}{2}$. Likewise, $P(F')$ is the probability of picking the unfair die, again *without* knowing the outcomes that you got. So $P(F') = \frac{1}{2}$ as well.

But again: what you want is to compute $P(F|O)$, because you *do* know that the outcomes are, and that will effect the probability of you having picked the fair die. For example, suppose the unfair die was such that it had a $0$ probability of getting a 6. Then knowing that you did get a 6 in your throws, the probability of having picked the unfair die becomes $P(F'|O) = 0$, and hence the probability of having picked the fair die becomes $P(F|O) = 1$.

Now, in your case, both the fair and the unfair die could have resulted in the outcomes you got, but which is more likely? Intuitively, the fact that you got a couple of 6's and no 1's all seems quite compatible with the unfair die, since that one has a preference for 6, and against 1. Now, the devil is in the details, and you will have to go through the actual calculations, but I bet $P(F|O) < P(F'|O)$!

Anyway, to finish your calculation for Bayes' formula, you still need to calculate the following:

$P(O|F)$: the probability of getting the values you got with the fair die

$P(O|F')$: the probability of getting the values you got with the unfair die

But I'll leave you to that!

Comment: Then the question has the implicit assumption that picking a die at random gives a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of choosing it, correct? Most people would assume this on intuition, but it feels misleading to make this an assumption when teaching someone introductory probability...

Comment: @KevinLong Yes, I can totally see that ... I'll add some comments, thanks!

Comment: I really appreciate all of the help everyone.  This entire class has been one giant struggle, but in a good way.

Comment: @Gabriel_W You're welcome!  And on the suggestion of KevinLong, I just added some more explanation to hopefully help you understand this a bit more conceptually.  Probabilities *are* confusing though! :)

Comment: @KevinLong I edited my answer ... I think it's better now, so thanks for your earlier comment!

Comment: @Bram28 Awesome.  Thank you so much you made this make so much more sense.  I came to a similar conclusion in that the given outcome seems to be consistent with the loaded die in that 6 appeared twice and there were no 1's.  However, that is where I hit a wall because I could definitely see some sort of connection I just did not know where to start.  Again, thank you.

Comment: @Gabriel_W Glad I could help out!  Do you think you can figure out $P(O|F)$ and $P(O|F')$ yourself?

Comment: @Bram28 I will give it my best attempt.  I really need to learn these concepts well since I am in school for Software Engineering.  Math has always been a difficult subject for me, I think it may be time to adjust some study habits.  If I run into anymore snags ill let you know.

Comment: @Gabriel_W All right: give it your best shot and if you're stuck feel free to send me a message

Comment: @Bram28 I'm glad to help. To clarify, I thought your answer was already good before and that it was a failure of the textbook not to explicitly say that there was an equal chance of picking each die, but you've made it even better now.